# Example of Logs-based Metrics API?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, metrics

I'm having trouble finding the API documentation for creating/managing Logs-based Metrics.  Specifically I'm trying to create User-defined metrics as I do in the GUI and then use them for Alerting.

I've looked through the Monitoring and Logging APIs and ostensibly https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics is right, except listing MetricDescriptors does not list the items I want to create so I'm thinking it's incorrect.

If anyone can help provide the API for Logs-based Metrics, or the API for listing System-defined metrics or User-defined metrics that would help me a ton

Comment: See [Log-based Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @DazWilkin. I don't know how I'm so lost because it's so straightforward but appreciate it!  :)

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/projects.metrics